# trying to fix the problems arising from asynchronous code in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in database systems and what I am trying to do is to check whether the e-mail entered by the user during login exists in the database or not. I use Firebase Databse. So, the code I have written is this:

```
function login(){
    var e_mail = document.getElementById("e-mail").value;
    rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    rootRef.orderByChild("E_mail").on("child_added", function(snapshot){
        lst.push(snapshot.val().E_mail);
        //console.log(lst);
    })
    console.log(lst);
}

let lst = [];
login_btn.onclick = function() {login()};
```

I want to fetch all e-mails from the database, add them in the list and then loop through that list. Maybe this is not the best way, but that's what I'm working on. I could also just say `if (snapshot.val().E_mail == e_mail){alert("there is such a user");}`but the problem I have encountered and want to deal with is not that, it's the "callback" function inside login function. When I console the list in the outer function it shows an empty list as it does not run the inner function until it is done with the outer one. I understand this. But how can I avoid or fix this. I want to get the full list of e-mails to be able to loop through it then. Also, I don't know how to end the "loop" in Firebase, because it is sort of looping when it gets the e-mails. So I would like to stop at the moment when it finds a matching e-mail.

Comment: loop through them where you have them ... in the callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well, but the problem with that is that I need to terminate taking the snapshots of the e-mails as soon as I find a matching one, because I am getting as many alerts (whether the user exists or not) as many e-mails there is in the database. @JaromandaX

Comment: are you saying you need to "cancel" (for want of a better term) the `.on("child_added"` handler?

Comment: yes, sort of. Although I doubt that it is possible. @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're downloading all users to see if one name exists already. That is a waste of bandwidth.

Instead you should use a query to match the email you're looking for, and only read that node:

```
rootRef.orderByChild("E_mail").equalTo(e_mail).once("value", function(snapshot){
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        // A node with the requested email already exists
    }
})
```

---

In general, if you need to process all nodes, you'll want to use a `value` event, which executes for all matching nodes at once. So to get all users from the database, add them to a list, and then do something with that list:

```
rootRef.orderByChild("E_mail").once("value", function(snapshot){
    var list = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        list.push(childSnapshot.val());
    });
    console.log(list); // this will display the populated array
})
```

Note that you won't be able to access the `list` outside of the callback. Even if you declare the variable outside of the callback, it will only be properly populated *inside* the callback. See Xufox' comment for a link explaining why that is.